# proc_macro_attribute seems to not play nicely with struct impls and traits

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I'm trying to get a procedural macro to print out information about variables in my function inputs. When I test the macro in a separate crate, I get an error from the compiler that I'm not implementing the trait functions even though the trait functions are clearly implemented.

Please ignore that the attr isn't returning anything yet; I'm building it together but ran into this issue first.

The procedural macro definition:

```
extern crate proc_macro;
use self::proc_macro::TokenStream;
use syn::{parse_macro_input, ItemFn};

#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn my_macro(attr: proc_macro::TokenStream, item: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    println!("item: \"{}\"", item.to_string());
    let func = parse_macro_input!(item as ItemFn);
    let input_funcs = func.sig.inputs
            .iter()
            .map(|item| println!("{:?}", try_me(item)));

    //input_funcs
    attr
}

fn try_me(arg: &syn::FnArg) -> String {
    match arg {
        syn::FnArg::Receiver(_r) => "is receiver".to_string(),
        syn::FnArg::Typed(_p) => "is pattern type".to_string()
    }
}
```

the testing crate:

```
use my_macro::{my_macro};

pub trait TestTrait {
    #[my_macro]
    fn my_func(&self, x: u8, y: String) -> u32 {
        return 0;
    }
    #[my_macro]
    fn empty_func(&mut self);
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    // Note this useful idiom: importing names from outer (for mod tests) scope.
    use super::*;
    #[derive(Default)]
    struct MyStruct{
        pub a: u8
    }
    impl TestTrait for MyStruct{
        #[my_macro]
        fn my_func(&self, _x: u8, _y: String) -> u32 {
            return 0;
        }
        #[my_macro]
        fn empty_func(&mut self) {
            self.a = 5;
        }
    }
    #[test]
    fn test_empty_func() {
        let mut struc = MyStruct::default();
        let interface = &mut struc as &mut dyn TestTrait;
        interface.empty_func();
        assert_eq!(5, contract.a);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_macros() {
            let mut struct = MyStruct::default();
            let interface = &mut struc as &mut dyn TestTrait;
            let zero = interface.my_func(8, "hello".to_string());
    }
}
```

yields errors such as:

```
item: "fn my_func(&self, x: u8, y: String) -> u32 { return 0; }"
item: "fn my_func(&self, x: u8, y: String) -> u32 { return 0; }"
item: "fn empty_func(&mut self);"
item: "fn empty_func(&mut self);"
error: expected curly braces
  |
9 |     fn empty_func(&mut self);
  |                             ^

error: expected curly braces
  |
9 |     fn empty_func(&mut self);
```

and

```
error[E0599]: no method named `empty_func` found for mutable reference `&mut dyn TestTrait` in the current scope
   |
34 |         interface.empty_func();
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `&mut dyn TestTrait`

error[E0599]: no method named `my_func` found for mutable reference `&mut dyn TestTrait` in the current scope
   |
42 |             let zero = interface.my_func(8, "hello".to_string());
   |                                  ^^^^^^^ method not found in `&mut dyn TestTrait`
```

If I take off the procedural macro attribute, this compiles. What is going on here and what should I do differently?

Comment: `my_macro` should return `item`, not `attr`.

Answer (score 1):

Found this out after discussion in the Rust Discord. Props to Jebrosen. The problem is that I'm returning `attr` and attr currently has nothing assigned to it. Thus when the compiler goes to expand the code it actually shrinks the code to...nothing. I am essentially deleting my code at compile time. Instead of doing this to test out the proc macro, I should instead use quote and quote the function as is while testing things out with printlns. Hope this helps someone in the future.